# confused on node 0.12 child_process.exec on error and on exit

Tags: node.js

so when i delete getLog.py and run the following code, on error was NOT called, how come ?

```
app.get('/getLog', isAuthenticated, hasLicense, function(req, res)
{
    console.log("getting log ......");
    logger.debug("getting log ......");

    var myCmd = exec('/usr/bin/python getLog.py');
    myCmd.on(('error'), function(code) {
        logger.error("Error running getLog.py");
        console.log("Error running getLog.py");
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
    myCmd.on(('exit'), function(code, signal) {
        console.log("Running getLog.py ok 1, code=" + signal);
        res.send(); 
    });
    myCmd.on(('close'), function(code, signal) {
        console.log("Running getLog.py ok 2, code=" + signal);
        res.send(); 
    });
    myCmd.on(('disconnect'), function(code, signal) {
        console.log("Running getLog.py ok 3, code=" + signal);
        res.send(); 
    });
});
```

getting log ......

[2016-04-21 13:01:17.832] [DEBUG] istar - getting log ......

Running getLog.py ok 1, code=null

Running getLog.py ok 2, code=null

Comment: Is it supposed to be called? The python script needs to exit with a non-zero exit code in order to cause the `error` event to be emitted. Also you should get rid of the unnecessary `()` around `'exit'`, `'close'`, etc. The don't do anything but make it harder to read

Comment: @aray12  in my test case, i physically deleted getLog.py, then load my webpage, i was hoping node.js emit some error event, but seems didn't caught that ...

Comment: Try adding `myCmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stdout: ' + data) });` and `myCmd.stderr.on('data', function(data) { console.log('stderr: ' + data) });` and see what the output is

Comment: @aray12  it hits stderr, not error, this is the part confuses me. Anyway i can stay with stderr for now. Thanks !